# Paypal subscription button - specify amount in form?

Tags: paypal

I've set up a subscription button using the guide [here](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_subscribe_buttons#id08ADF1008HS), however, it makes you select the price during the set up process.

Is there anyway I can define this value in the form, as the subscriptions I want to use will vary quite a lot depending on other factors.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to create buttons through your PayPal account you can't modify the HTML code to make the amount value (a3) be a text field. You'll need to create a custom button or an unhosted button so have the full HTML code and can change the "hidden" field to a "text" field.

When you're creating a new button through your account there is an option in Step 2: Track inventory, profit & loss you'll need to uncheck called "Save button at PayPal". After that you'll need to click the "Remove code protection" link to get the full HTML code you can modify however you want.